# Images in RTF field is not visible in HTML template emails

Tags: email-template, richtextarea

I have a custom RTF field in custom object which is used in HTML email templates. Normally this field would have images and text. The text content is visible in the email, but image is not visible in the emails received by the users.

I am using the following tag in the email template to display the rich text field (Special_notes__c):

{!custom_object__c.Special_notes__c}

what could be the possible reason and how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked with Salesforce Support. it seems Images in RTF field is not supported in Emails.

I got the following reply:

I informed you that this is because the image is not available externally and is only accessible by internal users can log in to your org. As I informed you, we recommend uploading images to the documents tab first if you want to send it via email.

Below is a related article that mentions we recommend uploading email template images to the Documents tab:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_custom_html_email_templates.htm&language=en_US

As a workaround, I suggested you to upload images from an external web address instead. When you add image in the rich text field, instead of uploading the image, you need to enter the URL of the image.